# How to get list size of child in firebase using java in andoird?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have some button , the button title will be change to "insert your pin" if `list size from child "pin" on firebase != 0` .

There , add new pin actually working , but how to detect if `size != 0`

**My Code :**

```
reference.child("pin").child(userID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Pin pinLogin = snapshot.getValue(Pin.class);
                    pinLogin.setKey(pinLogin.getKey());

                    pin.add(pinLogin);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

**My Button Logic :**

```
          if(pin.size == 0){
                        reference.child("pin").child(userID).push()
                                .setValue(new Pin(pinEditText))
                                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                        dialog.setTitleText("Success");
                                        dialog.setContentText("Pin Has Been Added!");
                                        dialog.show();
                                    }
                                })
                                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                        dialogError.setTitleText("Error");
                                        dialogError.setContentText(e.getMessage());
                                    }
                                });
                  }else{
                     button.setText("Insert Your Pin");
```

Any help will be appreciate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the size use `dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()`

```
reference.child("pin").child(userID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                long size= dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();

                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    // rest of code
```